# Cassandra service going out of cluster

Tags: cassandra

```
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2018-02-01 13:21:37,122 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 124290761766 for /172.xx.xx.xx
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2018-02-01 13:21:37,122 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 124290789451 for /172.xx.xx.xx
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2018-02-01 13:21:37,122 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 124290719057 for /172.xx.xx.xx
DEBUG [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.xx.xx.xx] 2018-02-01 13:21:56,430 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:106 - Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.xx.xx.xx] 2018-02-01 13:18:11,337 CassandraDaemon.java:217 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/172.xx.xx.xx,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR [RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:53336]] 2018-02-01 13:19:21,819 CassandraDaemon.java:217 - Exception in thread Thread[RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:53336],5,system]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
INFO [Service Thread] 2018-02-01 13:19:32,831 StatusLogger.java:56 - ValidationExecutor 0 0 0 0 0

ERROR [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.xx.x.xx] 2018-02-01 13:19:44,398 CassandraDaemon.java:217 - Exception in thread Thread[MessagingService-Incoming-/172.xx.xx.xx,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
INFO [HANDSHAKE-/172.xx.xx.xx] 2018-02-01 13:18:06,396 OutboundTcpConnection.java:514 - Handshaking version with /172.xx.xx.xx
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2018-02-01 13:21:37,121 StatusLogger.java:56 - CounterMutationStage
```

We have 13 nodes in production and Replication factor is 3. We are getting java heap memory error on every node every now and then.

Is there a solution for this?

If anyone wants the logs I am ready to provide.
Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you enabled the GC-Logs? This would be interesting to see. Furthermore it would be nice to see if you could provide some infos about the usage pattern. Does it fail on write? Do you have too much pending compactions? What does every now and then means? Hours? Days? Weeks?

Comment: Some more information about your cluster would be really helpful: what machines do you run on? what is your usage pattern and datamodel? what is the output of `nodetool tpstats`?

Comment: Running out of heap space memory could mean anything. Like others said, check logs, monitor mbeans, tweak some settings. Not sure what you want us to do.

Comment: Show the output of: `nodetool cfstats | grep "Compacted partition maximum bytes"` please.